# build a twitter feed with a database and intergrate it with flying swissmans slide script

Tags: jquery, database, twitter

Flying swissman provided this script,
[flyingSwissmans slide Script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766937/how-to-make-a-scroll-news-like-top-tweets-in-twitter-homepage-php)

it a jquery slider like the one twitter.com has.

I have problems understanding how i could doing what flyingswissman said..

> Then you give each div a unique id
>   each containing a comment from your
>   database. Initialize div 0,1,2 as
>   visible and 3-9 as hidden. - flyingswissman

Comment: Hi, cool to see my snippet is of help.What I'm trying to say is you need to make 10 divs with unique ids. The first three are to be visible the last 7 are to be hidden. That I've already done in the snippet. What exactly is the problem? Also, are you using php /MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the last lines of his example, he's making the 3 firsts div as "normal" then all other divs are set to `display:none`. He's doing it in PHP, but you can do the same with javascript.
Just make sure all your divs have an unique ID.